# What's the difference between OpenGL's workgroup size and local size?

Tags: c, go, opengl, graphics, shader

I've got trouble understanding the practical difference of the two.
Let's say I've defined my local_size as follows:

```
layout(local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32, local_size_z = 1)in;
```

Now I call:

```
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);
```

This results int 32 * 32 * 1 shader invocations, if I'm not mistaken.
So, where's the difference to this:

```
layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1)in;
```

And:

```
glDispatchCompute(32, 32, 1);
```

Comment: I think this question is not suitable for a site like SO, since to really answer that, one has to explain the whole concept of comupte shaders and its relation to GPU hardware archtiecture, which is way too much for a single question, and there are enough documentations online which do explain that ing reat detail.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious difference might be the support for [shared variables](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_variables) across invocations within a workgroup. In contrast to work groups all invocations within a work group are said to run in parallel. In general it is mostly about how your code maps to the hardware and its abilities to interface with it.

Comment: "In contrast to work groups all invocations within a work group are said to run in parallel." No ide who says that, but it is not backed up by the GL spec,  also what not really happens on the hardware in most situations.

Comment: @derhass The Khronos OpenGL wiki says that right at the end of the ["compute space" paragraph](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Execution_model)

Comment: It is put in quotation marks there for a reason, although I think the wording is unfortunate there still. However, the definitive source for the behavior of GL implementations is the spec, and it makes it very clear that you can't make any assumptions on the execution order between invocations within a workgroup, unless you explicitly use some of the sync mechanisms.

Comment: @derhass "___are said to___ to run in parallel" was meant to convey exactly that questionability...